# Why not use hash table with overflow area?

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

Seems that using a hashtable with an overflow area (either within the table or another table) is not suggested as part of usual hash table implementations (linear/quadratic probing, chaining etc).
I was wondering why not?
If we dedicate a fixed size for overflow e.g. H then   we have all the benefits of linear probing but without having to do O(N) searches where N is the size of the hash table but O(K) searches which is the size of the overflow area which could be kept small (in relation to N).
Is there any problem with this approach I am not seeing?

Comment: How is this different from storing a list of values whenever there is a collision?  (Preferably using some sort of tree for more efficient performance.)

Comment: adding a bunch of complexity to delay growing the table by a couple of inserts doesn't sound like much of a win in the general case.

Comment: Let's take the idea further.  You resolve problems in your hash table by going to the overflow.  You resolve problems in the overflow by going to your hash table.  You resolve problems with both by rewriting everything.

Congratulations, that's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing and it works well.

Comment: @btilly:I don't follow you. The overflow area is just a linear scan.So add as long as there is space, linear scan on get and resize on no space

Comment: @JayKominek:But linear probing is better than external chaining for small loads. We could get the benefits of linear probing without having to do a O(N) scan

Comment: @GordonLinoff:Better cache locality as they are part of the same table. The tree would access random pages which could lead to swaping

Comment: So how would your "overflow area" work? What's its complexity?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:O(K) where K is a fixed size and not O(N) i.e. the size of the whole table. K as a size can be a small percentage of the size of the table e.g. 0.1

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:Any collision of any bucket would go to the overlow area. When the overflow area is full or no more buckets left then resize the table. A linear scan of the overflow area would be the way to get the element. I.e. if the element in the bucket is not the one we are searching then linear search in the overflow area

Comment: So you replace an O(1) average lookup with a linear scan of the overflow area? Whis is O(K)? Which is, BTW O(N) /constants get ignored in O analysis/?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: First of all hash tables do not have O(1) average look up in reality. E.g. for external chaining we follow a list of links. And instead of folllowing K random places in memory we would access K places of an array in the same page. Also O(K) is not O(N) but is ~O(1). We could define a K that is reasonable for any table size so that it is O(1) i.e. irrelevant on how much the table grows

Comment: It's O(1) *average* (the average chain is very short). And make up your mind, first you said it's a small *percentage* - that is, it's O(N), now you want a fixed size. Which will almost guaranteed to quickly fill up if N is large. "Is there any problem with this approach I am not seeing?" - and to answer your question, you don't think these things through. There's a chasm between a wild idea and an actual algorithm with proper analysis.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:But I think that overflow areas are used in file systems. I was wondering how come this approach has not been analyzed (and even rejected) for hash tables in memory.

Comment: Maybe beause it's not a good idea?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:`It's O(1) average (the average chain is very short).` That means that the distribution is good which means that there are few collission which means that K could be small

Comment: You made an argument, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jim The structure of the overflow area was not specified.  I was describing one where the overflow area is itself a hash for efficiency.

Comment: *"but O(K) searches which is the size of the overflow area which could be kept small (in relation to N)"* - ***how*** can it be kept small? Even with *cryptographic* hash function strength (which is *slow*) and only 0.5 load factor, you'll have ~5% of elements elements "overflow": notice that's a fixed proportion independent of N so is O(N); too many to do linear searches in without completely ruining your hash table performance characteristics.